# como pegar todas as imagens com foreach

Tags: php

como faço para pegar todas as `img` com o foreach e mandar por `email`, coloquei minha função de enviar o `email` dentro do laço mas não vai ele me envia só a primeira e se eu colocar a função fora do laço ele me envia a ultima alguém poderia me ajudar?

código

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
        foreach($_POST['ck'] as $ck){
            $msg = "<img src=\"http://www.site.com.br/images/$ck\"width=\"100px\" height=\"70px\"><br>";

                // manda e-mail usuario
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail-> IsSMTP();
                $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->Port = 587;
                $mail->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
                $mail->Username = "usuario@exemplo.com";
                $mail->Password = "senha";
                $mail->SetFrom("usuario@exemplo.com", "usuario");

                $mail->AddAddress("recebedor@exemplo.com", "usuario");
                $mail->Subject = "assunto";
                $mail->msgHTML($msg);

                if($mail->send()){
                    echo "enviado com sucesso";
                    exit();
                }else{
                    echo "Erro ao enviar o email".$mail->ErrorInfo;
                }
            }       

    }
```

Comment: Em um email vc quer ter várias imagens ou quer uma imagem por email?

Comment: em um email varias img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixe de fora do foreach tudo aquilo que não varia, como a criação do objeto do PHPMailer e o envia do email. Usa a propriedade `Body` para formatar/manipular/atribuir a mensgem do email.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail-> IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
    $mail->Username = "usuario@exemplo.com";
    $mail->Password = "senha";
    $mail->SetFrom("usuario@exemplo.com", "usuario");
    $mail->Subject = "assunto";
    $mail->AddAddress("recebedor@exemplo.com", "usuario");

    foreach($_POST['ck'] as $ck){
        $msg = "<img src=\"http://www.site.com.br/images/$ck\"width=\"100px\" height=\"70px\"><br>";
        $mail->Body .= $msg;
    }

    if($mail->send()){
        echo "enviado com sucesso";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao enviar o email".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }           
}
```

Comment: intendi obrigado pela ajuda cara. agora funcionou!